# What options do I have for a DC disconnect switch ~72VDC ~7A

Tags: switches, dc, safety, switching

I'm would like to implement a disconnect switch between my [power supply](https://www.belfuse.com/product/part-details?partn=LDC480-72P) and my system. Both the power supply and my system are fused, but I'd like the ability to safely disconnect the system for service.

I was looking at using something like a [switchable contact block (page 13)](http://www.ia.omron.com/data_pdf/cat/a22n_m22n_a30n_a254-e1_4_6_csm1045427.pdf) but the majority of them won't support the voltage / current combination I intend on having.

What other options should I consider for this operation?

Comment: You could use a connector rated for the voltage/current combination and just short the pins on the plug together.

Comment: Alternately if you have access to the DIN rail itself you can just pull that contact block out of the power supply.

Comment: @vir thanks for the suggestion, any suggestions for something that's mechanically switchable? Both solutions seem like they would be intimidating for the end-user in this application.

Comment: There's always circuit breakers.  Plenty of 125VDC breakers that could also replace the fuse on your system.

Comment: @vir I'll take a look into it. I'm using some off the shelf devices which have fuses built in, but this could possibly work! Thanks

Comment: Perko battery switches are not rated for 72V, but I suspect they would work fine regardless. Depends on whether you are comfortable with the lack of official approval. If you don't mind large, there are certainly DC rated safety disconnects going up to 600V for solar panels and such. Expensive and large, though.

Comment: https://www.industrialcontroldirect.com/panel-mount-dc-switch-si16-pm64-2-6060.html?zenid=p7nl4fp7dj6j4jen58fbh0fd91

Comment: @mkeith while this link doesn't have a datasheet, I looked up the part number on Newark and found the subcategory where these are. Thank you for getting me along the right path!

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what price range or size of switch you are looking for.

There are some quite substantial DC isolator switches used in solar power installations.  they have to switch hundreds of volts DC, at tens of amps.  Even the smaller ones should be suitable for your purpose.